# Why e is not used in Javascript methods called from onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, dom-events

As far as I know `e` represent "event" in Javascript methods, but I do not understand what if I want to use some properties as mentioned below in the Javascript methods when I call them.

For example I can use `e.preventDefault()` or `e.ctrlKey` in this method :

```
$(".menuItem").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    //Open url in new tab with ctrl key press
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        window.open(url, '_blank');
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }

    //... code omitted for brevity
});
```

But I cannot use them in that method called from form elements i.e. `.menuItem`. Is there a possibility to use it in that method below?

```
function TestFunction(e, controller, action) {

        e.preventDefault();

        //Open url in new tab with ctrl key press
        if (e.ctrlKey) {
            window.open(url, '_blank');
            event.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }

        //... code omitted for brevity
    });
};
```

**Update:** I call the TestFunction() as shown below:

```
<a onclick="TestFunction('Account', '_Register')" id="test" class="nav-link ">
```

When I use e in that method *"Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined"* error is encountered. Any idea?

Comment: as you can see, there is no `e` parameter in your `TestFunction`, you need to add it

Comment: Yes, but when using it I encounter an error mentioned in the question. I added e parameter to the question also. Any idea?

Comment: How do you bind the `TestFunction` with the click event ? do you have in your code `$(".menuItem").click(TestFunction);` ?

Comment: try with `<a onclick="TestFunction.bind(null,'Account', '_Register')"` with `TestFunction` like this : `function TestFunction(controller, action, e) {`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder "TypeError: e is null" error is encountered.

Comment: @binary: You don't change the question to incorporate answers; it makes the answers not make sense. I've rolled back the edits trying to fold answers into the question. Re `TypeError: e is null`: You won't get that with the code in my answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I know "e" represent "event" in Javascript methods

Only by convention, because people use that name to declare the argument the event handler receives. It could be `gonzofish` just as easily.

You can't use an event object in `TestFunction` unless whatever calls it is responding to an event and passes the event object into it.

Update: You've said you're calling `TestFunction` like this:

```
<a onclick="TestFunction(e, 'Account', '_Register')" id="test" class="nav-link ">
```

If so, change `TestFunction` to:

```
function TestFunction(e, controller, action)`
```

...and use `e` (not `event`) consistently within it, and change that `onclick` attribute to use `event`, not `e`:

```
<a onclick="TestFunction(event, 'Account', '_Register')" id="test" class="nav-link ">
```

In an `onxyz` attribute event handler, `event` is an in-scope variable (on most browsers, it's local to the generated function created around your attribute text; on old IE, it's a global).

---

Side note: You might periodically see `event` (rather than `e`) without it being declared. Microsoft's IE used to have (probably still does) a global `event` object (and Chrome decided to throw web sites written for IE a bone and replicate that; Firefox did not). Don't use it. Instead, use proper event handling and declare the argument you receive.

Side note 2: Re `TestFunction`, the overwhelming convention in JavaScript is that function names only start with a capital letter when they're constructor functions (e.g.,  meant to be used with `new`). All other function names, by convention, should start with a lowercase letter. You can choose not to follow convention, of course, but it makes it easier for you to read other people's code and vice-versa if you follow the convention.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed explanations. I updated my code in my question and now it is working. In that case can we say that "e events can also be used for the javascript methods called like that?"

Comment: @binary: The key thing here is that `e` is just the name of an argument. The argument is determined by how the function is called. In a proper event handler (hooked up with `addEventListener`), the event mechanism passes the argumetn to the function fo ryou. If you use `onxyz` attributes, you need to pass it explicitly, using the `event` variable the code in your attribute has access to.

Answer (score -1):

event **OR** e can only be used in event. and you are going to access in function.

To use in function you have to pass parameter from event.

```
function TestFunction(controller, action,e) {.....
```

Comment: I am not downwoter, but just for information I also tried the same way but did not work :(

Comment: thanks, have you pass that parameter from click event?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is the name of the parameter in the function as Rayon mentioned (I changed from event to e). Voted+ for your help.

Comment: appreciate your response